# How to group a List of records by fields into an Object with Lists inside

Tags: java, list, dictionary, stream, groupingby

I've tried to figure out how to do this but i'm stuck and i would like some help.

After having done a complex SQL Query and having assigned its result to a JPA Entity that maps this query result as if it was a view, i have this List, where each entry is of the kind (the List of these records is called resultList):

*rowId, cf, c1, c2, dt, sx rsd, id_c, cost, gest, **idImp**, descImp, costImp, **idPren**, descPren*

> 1, XXXXX, C1, C2, DT, SX, RSD, ID_C, COST, GEST, **IDIMP1**, DESCIMP1,
> COSTIMP1, **IDPREN1_1**, DESCPREN1_1
>
> 2, XXXXX, C1, C2, DT, SX, RSD, ID_C, COST, GEST, **IDIMP1**, DESCIMP1,
> COSTIMP1, **IDPREN1_2**, DESCPREN1_2
>
> 3, XXXXX, C1, C2, DT, SX, RSD, ID_C, COST, GEST, **IDIMP2**, DESCIMP1,
> COSTIMP1, **IDPREN2_1**, DESCPREN2_1

All the fields before **idImp** are, because of the query, always the same.
I'm trying to gather all these records into an object of class ResultContainerGrouped, which has Lists for the variable elements.
So the 3 entries would became:

> XXXXX, C1, C2, DT, SX, RSD, ID_C, COST, GEST, { [**IDIMP1**, DESCIMP1, COSTIMP1 {[**IDPREN1_1**, DESCPREN1_1], [**IDPREN1_2**, DESCPREN1_2]} ], [**IDIMP2**, DESCIMP1, COSTIMP1 { [ **IDPREN2_1**, DESCPREN2_1 ] } ] }

```
public class ResultContainerGrouped{
    protected String cf;
    protected String c1;
    protected String c2;
    protected String dt;
    protected String sx;
    protected String rsd;
    protected String id_c;
    protected String cost;
    protected String gest;
    protected List<Imp> listR;
}



public class Imp{
    protected String idImp;
    protected String descImp;
    protected String costImp;
    protected List<Pren> listP;
}



public class Pren{
    protected String idPren;
    protected String descPren;
}



public class ResultContainerRecords{
        protected String cf;
        protected String c1;
        protected String c2;
        protected String dt;
        protected String sx;
        protected String rsd;
        protected String id_c;
        protected String cost;
        protected String gest;
        // represents List<Imp> listR;
        protected String idImp;
        protected String descImp;
        protected String costImp;
        // represents List<Pren> listP;
        protected String idPren;
        protected String descPren;
    }
```

I had thought to use streams (I am not familiar with stream and i'm trying to getting used to it), but i don't know if it's fitting given that i have different keys (I should groupBy first for idImp, then for idPren?)

I actually got to groupBy idImp, but i don't know how to do with the other list inside idImp.

I set the static values with:

```
resultContainerGrouped.setCf(resultList.get(0).getCf())
...
```

then i used stream to group by the ListR, but i don't know how to work with ListP inside ListR.

```
Map<String, List<ResultContainerRecords>> mapR = resultList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ResultContainerRecords::idImp));
            
mapR.values().stream().forEach(x -> resultContainerGrouped.getListR().add(buildR(x)));
```

where buildR is a method used to create a List for each mapR value to responseGrouped's ListR

```
private ListR buildR (List<ResultContainerRecords> x) {
ListR result = new ListR();

result.setCostImp(x.get(0).getCostImp());
result.setIdImp(x.get(0).getIdImp());
if ((!StringUtils.isEmpty(x.get(0).getDescImp())))
    result.setDescImp(x.get(0).getDescImp());

return result;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your attempt (not necessarily with streams).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko as soon as i will get back to my laptop i will, sorry

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to group again, inside the method where i would build objects from the records.

```
Map<String, List<ResultContainerRecords>> mapR = resultList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ResultContainerRecords::idImp));
            
mapR.values().stream().forEach(x -> resultContainerGrouped.getListR().add(buildR(x)));
```

with buildR being

```
private ListR buildR (List<ResultContainerRecords> x) {  
ListR result = new ListR();
List<ListP> listP = new ArrayList<>();

result.setCostImp(x.get(0).getCostImp());
result.setIdImp(x.get(0).getIdImp());
if ((!StringUtils.isEmpty(x.get(0).getDescImp())))   result.setDescImp(x.get(0).getDescImp());

Map<String, List< ResultContainerRecords >> mapR = x.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ResultContainerRecords::getIdPren)); 
mapR.values().stream().forEach(y -> result.getListP().add(buildP(y)));

result.getListP().addAll(listP);

return result;
}
```

Lastly buildP, for Pren

```
private ListP buildP (List< ResultContainerRecords > y) {
        ListPr result = new ListP();

        result.setIdPren(z.get(0).getIdPren());
        result.setDescPren(z.get(0).getDescPren());

        return result;
    }
```